# Typeahead seems to lag one $http request behind, whats the bug here?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I know Customizing out of the box typeahead directive is not a good idea, so went ahead and created another directive called `type-ahead-custom` for my customization.

***here's*** **plunker** https://plnkr.co/edit/PmYRm37Uqn6CFYAXuUcl

**OUTPUT**

s = no results displayed on ui, even though we got back data from server.

so = Now you see the results of previous query results i.e 's', even though we got back data for 'so'

sou = Now you see the results of previous query results i.e 'so', even though we got back data for 'sou'

this continues.
**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="account" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label customize-label ">Typeahead</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="inner-addon right-addon">

          <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.planes" uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formatted_address for plane in data" type-ahead-custom="maps" typeahead-loading="loadingdata" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-4-8758" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

for example in above code `type-ahead-custom="maps"`is my directive, here i supply the table name to get data from (here for example sake i am just passing a string).

**Javascript**

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

exampleApp.directive('typeAheadCustom', function($http) {
return {
    priority: 1,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {

         $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/'+$attributes.typeAheadCustom+'/api/geocode/json', {
             params: {
                 address: newValue,
                 sensor: false
                 }
           }).success(function(data) {
              $scope.data = data.results;
          });

        });

    }
}
});
```

Since the DOM has both directive `type-ahead-custom` and `uib-typeahead`, i have given my directive `priority:1` to make it executes first.

**Problem**: with my directive in place, typeahead seems to lag one $http request behind while showing the data on UI.

For example, if you start by typing.

I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix this. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using $q service helped me with the same issue. I modified your code a little bit.

In your index.html change `plane in data` to `plane in search($viewValue)`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.planes" uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formatted_address for plane in search($viewValue)" type-ahead-custom="maps" typeahead-loading="loadingdata" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-4-8758" />
```

And in your `link` replace watcher with the `search` function that returns a promise.

```
$scope.search = function(newValue) {
    var dfr = $q.defer();
    $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/'+$attributes.typeAheadCustom+'/api/geocode/json', {
         params: {
             address: newValue,
             sensor: false
             }
         }).success(function(data) {   
              dfr.resolve(data.results);
         });
    return dfr.promise;
};
```

And of course, you need to inject $q service:

```
exampleApp.directive('typeAheadCustom', function($http, $q) {
...
```

Working plnkr exampe: https://plnkr.co/edit/oJBoV5M58tLHMvvSAOkS